# Google Classroom Restful API - TurnIn Assignments

Tags: json, rest, google-classroom

I'm trying to use Google Classroom's Rest resources (https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions#StudentSubmission) to implement a student posting an answer to a "Simple Question" assignment (i.e.: An assignment which takes only a string as the answer).

I've managed to list the student's courses, coursework and submissions using the Rest services. However, I'm finding it impossible to update the student's answer when using the Patch method (https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions/patch) to try and update Submission Data.

As of now I'm using the following body for my patch calls:

```
   {
      "courseId": "xxxxxxxx",
      "courseWorkId": "wwwwwwwww",
      "id": "sssssss",
      "userId": "wwwwwwwwwwwwwww",
      "creationTime": "2019-09-30T19:38:59.594Z",
      "updateTime": "2019-09-30T19:38:59.561Z",
      "state": "CREATED",
      "alternateLink": "https://classroom.google.com/c/aaa/sa/aaaa/submissions/student/aaaa",
      "courseWorkType": "SHORT_ANSWER_QUESTION",
      "shortAnswerSubmission": 
      {
         "answer":"Test Answer"
      }
    }
```

And the result is an Error 400 - Invalid JSON payload received..

Is there a way to make this happen - i.e.: for a third party software to update an answer from a student's assignment?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Forgot to mention - I'm using the querystring updateMask=shortAnswerSubmission

Comment: Apparently Patch is a method to be used only for teachers and so assign grades. Looked all over the internet and nobody is using to update student answers - only to set draftGrade and assignedGrade. 

Yet, due to the API description I am still unsure if there is a way to use this service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confirmed that Path is a method used just for teachers to post their evaluation. The only way to send student data using Google Classroom is through Attachments (actually their link) using a normal assignment.